# SQL query with foreign keys across three tables

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables `Product`, `User` and `Cart`.

In `Cart`, I have two foreign keys, one from each table, columns are called `userid` and `productid`.

These are my tables:

**User**:

```
Id || name  ||
```

**Product**:

```
Id || name
```

**Cart**:

```
Id|| userid || productid
```

What I want to do is to get all products through foreign key from cart table. Actually I want to get all product by userid. Is it possible? If yes can someone explain.

Comment: Kind of confused by what you're asking for but sounds like you need to join the tables on their primary and foreign keys. Have you got your current create table syntax? or table structures

Comment: Are you trying to do this via Java?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Product.*
FROM Cart c ,product p, user u
Where c.productID=p.productID 
AND c.userID= u.userID
AND u.userID=(Whatever user id you want)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id UserID, u.name UserName, p.id ProductID, p.name ProductName,
  c.id CartID
from cart c
  inner join product p on c.productid = p.id
  inner join user u on u.id = c.userid
```

This is a straight join of the information from your cart table with an alias of c to your product table with an alias of p, and then another join from your cart table to your user table with an alias of u.

The returned columns align with the assigned aliases.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.